# wget and ipv6 problem?

Tags: networking, wget, ipv6

When I try to download via wget I must use `--inet4-only` option.
otherwise I will get this:

```
mobin@mobinuntu:~/Desktop/bbb/bb-kernel$wget https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/6.3-2017.05/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz 
--2017-08-10 05:09:47--  https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/6.3-2017.05/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
Resolving releases.linaro.org (releases.linaro.org)... failed: No such file or directory.
 wget: unable to resolve host address ‘releases.linaro.org’
```

any ideas on solving this problem? (using wget without  `--inet4-only` option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to these man pages:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html
- https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/wget-1.8.1/html_chapter/wget_6.html

I just added `inet4_only = on` to `/etc/wgetrc` config file and this option is set globally to all wget commands.