# Terminal has network (DNS?) issues but browser works fine. ipv6 issue?

Tags: networking, command-line, ipv6, ipv4

EDIT: It seems it might be a cable modem issue: according to https://test-ipv6.com/ ipv6 is not working both in Ubuntu as well as windows (dual boot, same workstation), and neither on my smartphone when on wifi (i.e. same cable modem), while it does work on smartphone with wifi disabled (i.e. mobile data). So I will contact my ISP.

I have a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install on a desktop PC with a **wired** internet connection. It has the default networking configuration settings (DHCP; IP address from cable modem).

Internet access works fine from a browser.

From the command line however, some programs (e.g. `apt update` or `apt upgrade`) seem to work fine, though maybe somewhat slow (?), while others fail, e.g. `wget`:

```
~$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/rolling/ros2.repos
--2023-05-17 13:56:57--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/rolling/ros2.repos
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 2606:50c0:8002::154, 2606:50c0:8001::154, 2606:50c0:8000::154, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|2606:50c0:8002::154|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|2606:50c0:8001::154|:443... ^C
```

Accessing the same link from a webbrowser instantly loads the `ros2.repos` file.

Adding an entry "185.199.108.133  raw.githubusercontent.com" to `/etc/hosts` also solves the issue:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/rolling/ros2.repos
--2023-05-17 14:52:18--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/rolling/ros2.repos
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.108.133
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.108.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12144 (12K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘ros2.repos.1’

ros2.repos.1                                     100%[=======================================================================================================>]  11,86K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-05-17 14:52:18 (124 MB/s) - ‘ros2.repos.1’ saved [12144/12144]
```

So I think it is an `ipv4` vs `ipv6` issue.
Though I have no idea why it works from the browser but not from the terminal.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: Must be an IPv6 issue. I only get to see IPv4 addresses for that server.

Comment: @Jos It is not just that server, that's just an example. E.g.  
`ping www.google.com  
PING www.google.com(ams15s41-in-x04.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400e:802::2004)) 56 data bytes`  
does not work either, whereas ipv4 ping does work:  `ping -4 www.google.com
PING  (142.250.179.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ams15s41-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.179.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=30.7 ms`

Comment: Ignore my last comment.  You are having an IPv6 DNS issue.  I'll get back to ya about what to possibly check.  But, have you checked if your IPv6 is working in a web browser?  https://test-ipv6.com/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `wget` may have issues with IPv6 addresses occasionally. There is an option that can be set so that it always uses IPv4 addresses only:

Adding `inet4_only = on` to `/etc/wgetrc` should resolve this.

Credits to [wget and ipv6 problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944778/wget-and-ipv6-problem)

Comment: It is not a specific problem with `wget`, e.g. ping isn't working either for ipv6 addresses.

Comment: Okay, can you post the output of `ip a`? There is the option of disabling IPv6 altogether, if it acts erroneously. https://itsfoss.com/disable-ipv6-ubuntu-linux/